# Приложение не устанавливается.При отладке работает

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте.Приложение из файловой системы не устанавливается но из AndroidStudio отлично заливается и все работает.Утечек памяти нет,статических ссылок нет.Использую в одном месте яндекс карту.Много drawable файлов и в некоторых классах есть много текста в String и StringBuilder().Заливаю на android 4.4.2. Из за чего это может быть? При установке выходит <<Приложение не установлено>>

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"
    android:label="блаблабла"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <service android:name=".services.Timer_Alert"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:label="блаблабла"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Main3SignInActivity"
        android:label="блаблабла"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Main4RegistrationActivity"
        android:label="блаблабла"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".ProphileActivity"
        android:label="блаблабла"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".blabla"
        android:label="блаблабла"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".blabla"
        android:label="блаблабла"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".blabla"
        android:label="блаблабла"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MediaActivity"
        android:label="блаблабла"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".blabla"
        android:label="блаблабла"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".blabla"
        android:label="блаблабла"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />


    <activity android:name=".blabla"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="блаблабла"/>
    <activity android:name=".blabla"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="блаблабла"/>
    <activity android:name=".blabla"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="блаблабла"/>
    <activity android:name=".blabla"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="блаблабла"/>
    <activity android:name=".blabla"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="блаблабла"/>
</application>
```

## и build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.zverek.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandexmapkit-android/raw/maven/' }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'ru.yandex:yandexmapkit:2.5.4@aar'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно подписать приложение, чтобы устанавливать его из файловой системы: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Comment: Спасибо большое...Заработало!

Comment: сейчас добавлю в виде ответа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приложения для `android` могут устанавливаться `Android Studio` для отладки, и в таком случае подписывать `apk`-файл не нужно. Однако если вы хотите сделать `release`-сборку и залить ее, скажем, в `Google Play`, вам нужно [подписать](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) свой `apk` после сборки. По ссылочке вы найдете всю необходимую информацию.